How can I force g++ 5.4.0 to only use system headers that do not require C++11 support?
I am compiling C and C++ code for several platforms using Docker images provided by a different team. The other team provides different Docker images for each platform, and there is no uniformity as to which gcc and g++ version is available on each image. The other team is not very flexible on making changes to the images they provide.
When building for Ubuntu 16.04 with the provided Ubuntu 16.04 image, I get the following error, which I do not get when building for any other platform:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/type_traits:35:0,
                 from import/include/wx/strvararg.h:26,
                 from import/include/wx/string.h:51,
                 from import/include/wx/memory.h:16,
                 from import/include/wx/object.h:64,
                 from import/include/wx/wx.h:16,
                 from <redacted>.h:18,
                 from <redacted>.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support \
  ^

I cannot use -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11, as this will break the builds for the other platforms that use older compilers (we determined that for RedHat 6, we must use an older compiler that has no C++11 support).
The Ubuntu 16.04 Docker image has g++ 5.4.0 installed.
How can I force g++ 5.4.0 to only use system headers that do not require C++11 support? Is it even possible to do this?
I am compiling against wxWidgets 2.9.4. For reference, here are the first 33 lines of the import/include/wx/strvararg.h file:
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Name:        wx/strvararg.h
// Purpose:     macros for implementing type-safe vararg passing of strings
// Author:      Vaclav Slavik
// Created:     2007-02-19
// RCS-ID:      $Id$
// Copyright:   (c) 2007 REA Elektronik GmbH
// Licence:     wxWindows licence
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#ifndef _WX_STRVARARG_H_
#define _WX_STRVARARG_H_

#include "wx/platform.h"
#if wxONLY_WATCOM_EARLIER_THAN(1,4)
    #error "OpenWatcom version >= 1.4 is required to compile this code"
#endif

#include "wx/cpp.h"
#include "wx/chartype.h"
#include "wx/strconv.h"
#include "wx/buffer.h"
#include "wx/unichar.h"

#if defined(HAVE_TYPE_TRAITS)
    #include <type_traits>              // <- line 26
#elif defined(HAVE_TR1_TYPE_TRAITS)
    #ifdef __VISUALC__
        #include <type_traits>
    #else
        #include <tr1/type_traits>
    #endif
#endif


What's here from import/include/wx/strvararg.h:26, as <type_traits> was introduced in C++11 ? live - https://godbolt.org/z/KzG54jTK8

Looks like wxWidgets uses C++11.

@RichCritten, I added the start of import/include/wx/strvararg.h, including line 26. I am not sure if explicitly undefining HAVE_TYPE_TRAITS would break things.

I'm dealing with similar inconsistencies in my company, and it's just a royal *******. I'm not sure any group has a "very good reason" for not being able to update to a 13 year old standard. Thankfully for me, the issue is 14->17 and not 03->11.

Side note: gcc 5.4.0 is ancient. You really ought to upgrade to a recent compiler.

Can you add a Makefile or CMakefile to solve this on the particular platform? If so, I’ll write up an answer.
